# How to pass events from UIView to WKWebview underneath?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a WKWebview that I basically want to override the zooming behavior for. I want to scale up the font, so what I have right now is a UIView on top of the WKWebview that I've added a UIPinchGestureRecognizer to that does some evalutateJavascript call on the webview. However, now the Webview doesn't receive tapping or scrolling events as I believe the overlay view is capturing them. Is there a way to send it down to the webview? These are all in a single VC with outlets to both the webview and the overlay view. I wanted to override the behvaior directly for the WKWebview but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I know if you need to deliver gesture event to other responders, just set the  pinchGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false

Comment: This doesn't seem to capture the scrolling/panning gesture.

Comment: If you add tap gesture it on the webview should work. The other workaround is  func addTarget(_ wkwebview , action: Selector) for the first pan gesture. so you can try to figure how to handle in webview.